# calculate without using minus method in arrays

Tags: c#

I need to return b array which contain in every entry - b[i] of the array: the sum of array a(the input array) minus the element in a[i]. without using minus subtraction!

so the simple way is to sum the  a array

```
 for(i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
```

and to return `b[i] = sum - a[i];`. but how can I do it without using minus? :)

Thank you!

Comment: How can you do a subtraction without using subtraction?

Comment: Can you re-phrase your initial question, because to be honest, it's not very understandable

Comment: You mean without using subtraction or without using negation? You could just negate `a[i]` and add this but this seems likely a trivial thing if so

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] and sample inputs, and expected outputs for those sample ionputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
for(i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
{
    b[i] = sum; //sum without a[i] and no minus used
    sum += a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
b[i] = 0;
// sum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++)
{
    if (i != j)
    {
        b[i] += a[j];
    }
    // sum += a[i];
}
// b[i] == sum - a[i];
```

Comment: `b[1]` will have sum of all `a[j]` but `a|1]`